# how can i do the following query with Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
 ------------------  
 |    **table 1**  |
 ------------------
 | 1 | 400         |
 | 2 | 220         |
 | 3 | 123         |

 ------------------
 |    **table 2**  |
 ------------------
 | 1 | 100         |
```

formula : `table1 - table2 where table1.id=table2.id`

```
  ------------------
 |    **Result**    |
 ------------------
 | 1 | 300         |
 | 2 | 220         |
 | 3 | 123         |
```

Comment: What's the expected result if you add (4, 44) to table2? (I.e. with no matching row in table1.)

Comment: It will be the same result

Answer (score 3):

You want an outer join to get all rows from table_1 and the matching ones from table2

```
select t1.id, t1.val - coalesce(t2.val, 0) as result
from table_1 t1
  left join table_2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id;
```

The `coalesce(t2.val, 0)` is necessary because the outer join will return `null` for those rows where no id exists in table_2 but `t1.val - null` would yield `null`

Comment: An equivalent alternative to `coalesce`, used often in the Oracle community, is `nvl`. As in, `nvl(t2.val, 0)`.

Comment: @mathguy: why should I? `coalesce()` is standard SQL, `nvl()` is not.

Comment: You shouldn't (my writing style is quite direct; if I had thought you "should" use `nvl`, I would have said so). I just mentioned the alternative which will be found very often specifically in the Oracle community. For example on OTN you will very rarely see `coalesce`. If it were for me, `nvl` shouldn't even exist. {:-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select t1.col1, t1.col2-t2.col1 as balance from 
table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.col1=t2.col1
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - perhaps you are just being nice, but that's what downvotes are for. Do you ever use them?

Comment: Edited with LEFT JOIN :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.id,
       nvl2(t2.val,t1.val-t2.val,t1.val) val
from   t1,t2
where  t1.id=t2.id(+)
order  by t1.id;
```

Comment: I'm impressed, haven't seen that ancient Oracle outer join syntax in a long time!

Comment: @jarlh - sometimes that ancient join syntax (for ALL types of join) is unavoidable. Oracle bug: ANSI join syntax not supported for fast refresh MVs.

Comment: @mathguy: but this is not the right situation to use the old, outdated and fragile implicit joins. Even Oracle recommends to use the "new" syntax (which exists since Oracle 9)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Of course, I agree completely. I was just pointing out that "not seeing it in a long time" means also that one has not seen a fast refresh MV with joins in a long time. It is important for people to be aware of the Oracle syntax, and the cases when they have no choice but to use it.

Comment: I agree with both of you. Its better to know both the standards as sometimes there's a need to fix a legacy code which still follows Conventional standards. However it is better to move on to ANSI to be more compatible with the new Oracle releases.

Answer (score 0):

I don't the syntax in Oracle sql, but I can give the solution in mysql.
Consider the table with 2 columns:
 id , value

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.value - table2.value 
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.id=table2.id
OR
SELECT table1.id, table1.value 
FROM table1, table2 
WHERE NOT (table1.id =table2.id)
```

Comment: This will return only one row (with id=1) not all three rows

Answer (score 0):

In some cases using scalar subquery caching could give better performance. It is on developer to compare execution plans and decide which query is the most appropriate.

```
with t1 (id, num) as
(
  select 1, 400 from dual union all
  select 2, 220 from dual union all
  select 3, 123 from dual
),
t2(id, num) as
(
  select 1, 100 from dual
)
select id,
       num - nvl((select num from t2 where t2.id = t1.id), 0) result
  from t1;
```

This is just to show you a different technique for solving problems in which you try to get data from several tables, but some may not have matching rows.

Using outer join in this case is in my opinion more logical.